# Magento 2 How to remove footer by website Id?

Tags: magento2, layout, footer, footer-links

Hi I am having multi website, I want to remove entire footer from website id 3.
here is my xml file

```
Ubertheme/shop/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
```

here added the code.

```
  <referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="true" />
```

This is removing footer from all websites. How to make it for only website Id 3.
Can I Get help?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this below process:

Create a unique layout handle for that website only. Like **website_3** and use the observer event **layout_load_before**

**Observer code**

```
class LayoutLoadBefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
       if ($this->storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId() == 3) {
           $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();

           $handlecode ='website_'.$this->storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
           $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle($handlecode);
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

**Layout code for that file**

app/code/{Vendorname}/{Module Name}/view/frontend/layout/website_3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: this is working like charm. Thank you so much for answer @Ritesh Santra